# param is missing or the value is empty: post in Postscontroller#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a Website with Posts and stuff.

Currently I have a Post Model with its components.

Whenever I try to open posts/new this error message appears

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in PostsController#new
param is missing or the value is empty: post
```

post_controller

```
def new
      @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save!
      redirect_to @post
    else

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
  end
```

I was able to create posts on `localhost:3000/post/new` before. I just wanted to try again and realized I must've messed something up. 
This is my Post form.

```
<div class="form-control">
  <div class="card-my-4">
    <%= form_for Post.new do |f| %>
      <div class="card-body">
        <strong>post title: </strong>
        <%= f.text_area :title, :maxlength => 40, class: 'form-control', rows: 1, id: 'textareaedit' %>
      </div>

      <div class="card-body">
        <strong>Compose your Quote content: </strong>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.text_area :body, :maxlength => 240, class: 'form-control', rows: 3 %>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <%= submit_tag "Submit", class: "btn btn-outline-success" %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 240 }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try change your code:

post_controller:

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
  if @post.save!
    redirect_to @post
  else
  ....
end
def new
  @post = Post.new
end
```

views:

```
<div class="form-control">
  <div class="card-my-4">
    <%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    ............
```

Comment: that did it. do you know why this worked before? i've always had my controller method new defined like that but was able to create posts before

Comment: if you want define in `new`. don't use `post_params`